# Javascript: variable is not undefined but while returning, being returned undefined

Tags: javascript

In the snippet below, before `return(res)` , I log it, and it's not `undefined`

but somehow, it's being returned as `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
filterData = (inputData, searchedKey) => {
  inputData.forEach((data, index) => {
    if(data){
      if(data.hasOwnProperty(searchedKey)){
        const res = data[searchedKey]
        console.log(res) /// logs the results
        return(res) /// returns undefined
      }
      var dataToProcess = [];

      var fieldKeys = Object.keys(data)
      fieldKeys = fieldKeys.filter((field, index) => !field.includes("#"))
      fieldKeys.forEach((key, index) => {
        dataToProcess.push(data[key]);
      })
      this.filterData(dataToProcess, searchedKey)
    }
  })
}

console.log(this.filterData([{"#name": "foo", "#type": "bar"}], "#type"))
```

Comment: how exactly do you plan to 'return' from a `forEach` ?

Comment: `filterData` is not returning anything, so logically that prints `undefined`

Comment: what return(res) is? a function invocation with res as input? where is the return function? please supplement your code, or rather use the return keyword

edit: see @Dellirium 's comment, you cannot return from foreach

edit2: gosh, i didnt know its a valid return statement: return(something)

Comment: Returning from `forEach` has no effect on container function. Use `for` or `for...of` loop instead of `forEach` if you want to immediately return from a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- `forEach` does not return anything else than `undefined`, so returning a value in its callback function does not do anything useful.
- Your function does not return a value
- The return value of the recursive call is not used.
- `if (data)` is not good enough to make sure `data` is an object. For instance, it would also be true for a non-zero number. Use `Object(data) === data` instead.
- Since there could be multiple matches (in a nested input object), your function should return an array, which is also what someone would expect when seeing your function name. Also the standard array `filter` method returns an array. So it would be in line with that.

Here is how you could make it work:

```js
var filterData = (inputData, searchedKey) => {
    inputData = inputData.filter( data => Object(data) === data );
    return !inputData.length ? [] :
        inputData.filter( data => data.hasOwnProperty(searchedKey) )
            .map( data => data[searchedKey] )
            // Add the results from recursion:
            .concat(filterData([].concat(...
                inputData.map( data =>
                    Object.keys(data)
                        .filter( key => !key.startsWith("#") )
                        .map( key => data[key] )
                )
            ), searchedKey));
};

var data = [{
    "#name": "foo", 
    "#title": "mr",
    "deeper": [{
        "#nope": "bad",
        "deepest": [{
            "nothing_here": null,
            "#type": "deeper bar",
        }]
    }, {
        "#type": "bar",
    }]
}];

console.log(filterData(data, "#type"));
```

If you need only the first match, then use this variant:

```js
var filterData = (inputData, searchedKey) => {
    inputData = inputData.filter( data => Object(data) === data );
    var res = inputData.find( data => data.hasOwnProperty(searchedKey) );
    return res !== undefined ? res[searchedKey] :
        // Try in nested objects:
        filterData([].concat(...
            inputData.map( data =>
                Object.keys(data)
                    .filter( key => !key.startsWith("#") )
                    .map( key => data[key] )
            )
        ), searchedKey);
};

var data = [{
    "#name": "foo", 
    "#title": "mr",
    "deeper": [{
        "#nope": "bad",
        "deepest": [{
            "nothing_here": null,
            "#type": "deeper bar",
        }]
    }, {
        "#type": "bar",
    }]
}];

console.log(filterData(data, "#type"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me a lot. But I need to return as soon as I find the first match, I don't need more than one result. there are gonna be many matches, I just need the first match. How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I added solution for getting first match.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```js
filterData = (inputData, searchedKey) => {
  return inputData.map((data, index) => {
    if(data){
      if(data.hasOwnProperty(searchedKey)){
        const res = data[searchedKey]
        console.log(res) /// logs the results
        return(res) /// returns undefined
      }
      var dataToProcess = [];

      var fieldKeys = Object.keys(data)
      fieldKeys = fieldKeys.filter((field, index) => !field.includes("#"))
      fieldKeys.forEach((key, index) => {
        dataToProcess.push(data[key]);
      })
      this.filterData(dataToProcess, searchedKey)
    }
  })
}

console.log(this.filterData([{"#name": "foo", "#type": "bar"}], "#type"))
```

Use [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example), it's pretty useful in many cases.